# Add a day to all cells with dates in the column

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I am using Access 2007. I want a form button, which would add one day to all cells with dates in column C, named "Next revision".

It seems Access doesn't recognize the "Range" function.

This code results in an error

> User-defined sub is not defined

I believe it would work in modern Excel, but not in old Access:

```vb
Skip_day_button_Click()
Dim myCell As Range
For Each myCell In Range(Cells(1, "C"), Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
    If IsDate(myCell) Then myCell = CDate(myCell) + 1
Next
End Sub
```

This works for an active row. How do I apply it to the whole column?

If [Next revision field] > 0 Then [Next revision field] = [Next revision field] + 1

Comment: Access has an entirely different object model from Excel. You need to work with the recordset, Range isn't a thing.

Comment: You need to study a guide or tutorial like "Beginning with Microsoft Access" to learn about forms, tables, recordsets, and queries.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for directing me to the recordset, recearching! So far I came up with a simple solution:

```
    Private Sub Skip_day_button_Click()
     DoCmd.ShowAllRecords
     DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acFirst
     Do While [Next revision field] > 0
        [Next revision field] = [Next revision field] + 1
     DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNext
     Loop
     DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Next revision] <= Date ()"
    End Sub
```

It takes 5 seconds to update 330 records. Will the recordset method work faster?